# Calculating real part of a square wave

Tags: fourier, class-d

i'm trying to understand how Bruno putzey in
[Globally Modulated Self-Oscillating Amplifier with Improved Linearity](http://www.hypex.nl/docs/papers/globally.pdf)
in section 4.2 Analysis comes to the equation in presented in (2), see snapshot below.
I've tried to do common fourieseri of a square, wave but i do not get the same answear, it annoys me very hard!

I wish someone could help me understand how to come to the same answear?

[image]

More information:
I've tried to calculate the rectangulare fourier series,but I still do not come to the same result as in the article, but I think I'm getting closer.

Se link to calculations in comments (due to not enough reputation)

Comment: Are you familiar with sin and cosine expressed as a Euler identity?

Comment: Yes, but I can't get to the same result.

Comment: I can't really help any more - I thought it might be related but you've tried this route it seems. Maybe try the math stack exchange?

Comment: Maybe I should.

However my first comment should have been:

After a look at wikipedia I'm a bit familiar with Eulers identity. If it's the same as the coordinate on the unity circle.

But I do know euler formula, which I used when transforming the sin part to exponential expression, however I do not get the same result.

For me:
The part "2*h-1" does not exist and n should only be odd numbers and the exponential part do not look a like.

Comment: It is a misnomer to call it a square wave when this is only true for h=50% duty cycle and only then are there no even harmonics.  It would be wiser to consider the recurring Rectangular pulse Fourier expression which has frequency nulls at n*f/h  e.g. h=10% has odd and even harmonics up 10f where it is null then repeats and next null at 20f while h=50% has 1st null at 2f then recursive 4f, 6f etc with an amplitude scale

Comment: http://www.thefouriertransform.com/series/coefficientsderivation.php

Comment: Thank you for the tips, but do u really mean f/h not h/f?
Feels like i'm getting closer but I still do not get the right/same result.

I look at the rectangular wave as the positive part with the width
h x T ( duty cycle x period) and the negative part as T(1-h).

Comment: Calculation:

Page1:  http://docdro.id/dKGlbRZ
Page2:  http://docdro.id/UPEntjC